# What does @Injectable mean?

Tags: angular

Does `@Injectable` mean that we can inject `MyService` into other classes or that we can inject other classes into `MyService`?

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {

  constructor() { }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked [documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/Injectable) before asking?

Comment: Yes, but I've encountered the second variant twice from two people, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Here is the opposite meaning:

For data or logic that isn't associated with a specific view, and that you want to share across components, you create a service class. A service class definition is immediately preceded by the @Injectable() decorator. The decorator provides the metadata that allows other providers to be injected as dependencies into your class.

https://angular.io/guide/architecture

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/27480 In short: @Injectable() means accepts dependency, not as dependency.

Answer (score 1):

@Injector is a decorator, when it is added to a service, this makes the service to be injected into the modules wherein it is needed as a dependency.

You can also inject other service marked with @Injector decorator into your service as a dependency

Do check

https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection

Answer (score 1):

Injectable() in the service specifies that this service can be injected/used in other components. In short if service has injectable decorator, other components can use that service by creating reference of service class in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

> @Injectable:
>
> Decorator that marks a class as available to be provided and injected
>   as a dependency.

You can read whole story here:

https://angular.io/api/core/Injectable